# I have a two node js servers. second server is for the socket connection. How do I establish a connection between these two servers?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm setting up another nodejs server for the socketio, which is index.js. so I have two servers one is app.js and other one is index.js. so how do i establish a connection between these two servers?

Comment: Provide some code that you have tried

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly get what you wanted to do. You wanted to separate the file of the recieving of socket. Here's my code below.

on your app.js

```
var app = Express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = SocketIo.listen(server);

server.listen(function(){
   require('/path/of/your/index.js')(io);
})
```

and on your index.js

```
module.exports = function(io){
  io.on('connection', function(socket){
    *your codes here*
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please explain your problem in detail.And second thing, I don't understand why you want to establish two servers.Because you can always connect socket.io using your Node server.The code for it is below:

```
//Server side code
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(80);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
  });
});

//Client Side code
var socket = io.connect();
socket.emit('my other event', {
     data : 'Hello'
});
```

This is very basic example for client-server communication using socket.io

I hope you will get your answer.